# no matching function for call basic_string::copy

Tags: c++, string, copy, stdstring

I'm very new to C++ and have been fidgeting around with it for awhile. If any insight is available with these errors I would be in great gratitude. The following program should produce the following result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string Cut(string &strString, int nStart, int nLength)
    {
        string strCopy;
        strString.copy(strCopy, nLength, nStart);
        strString.erase(nStart, nLength);
        return strCopy;
    }

int main()
{
    string strHate = "I hate tuna.";
    cout << strHate << endl;
    string strTuna;
    strTuna = Cut(strHate, 8, 4);
    cout << strHate << endl;
    cout << strTuna << endl;
}
```

should produce

```
I hate tuna.
I hate .
tuna
```

however, instead I get this error message:

```
9|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::copy(std::string&, int&, int&)'
```

Much appreciated,

KleptoKat

Comment: If you look at some documentation, or the rest of the error, it will say it accepts a `char *` (or whatever the string is using). I suggest using `substr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referenced [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/), the function `std::string.copy` takes a parameter of type `char *`, you you've given it a parameter of type `string`

This is a better solution:

```
string Cut(string &strString, int nStart, int nLength){
    string strCopy (strString, nStart, nLength);
    strString.erase(nStart, nLength);
    return strCopy;
}
```

This creates the *new* string from the *old* string directly from the constructor, so it's a little more elegant.

Just so you know *why* the error occurred, the data types of your variables (`int`, `char`, `string`, etc) have to match the data types that the function expects to receive. If you don't know what data types a function expects to receive, you can always look it up on Google.

Also, you need to use:

`strTuna = Cut(strHate, 7, 4)`

Instead of:

`strTuna = Cut(strHate, 8, 4)`

This is because the first character of the string has a position of `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Thanks, basic_string::copy was mentioned as a member string in std::string, so I just assumed it didn't use c-style strings. As for that little off-by-one error, we all make mistakes, dont we? ahaha

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised myself

Comment: @KleptoKat, You have to keep in mind we do have `std::string::substr` to copy to a `std::string`, `std::copy` to copy to either (and more), and `std::string::copy` to copy to a C string. I'm not sure why the last was implemented unless it uses `memmove` or something, but we already have two other things that will do C++ strings. And me being me, I forgot about the constructor which can copy from a pair of iterators as well, so that's 1 more for C++ strings, and it reminded me that `std::string::assign` can do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `string::substr` in your case is probably more appropriate:

```
string Cut(string &str, int nStart, int nLength)
{
  string strCopy = str.substr(nStart, nLength);
  str.erase(nStart, nLength);
  return strCopy;
}
```